# When approaching the gpio register address of RaspberryPi, why is the result different between unsigned int* and char*?

Tags: raspberry-pi, mmap, gpio

Using `mmap()`, I am going to write a value to the GPIO register address of the Raspberry Pi.

I thought the register value would have the same when reading mapped GPIO address in `unsigned int *` or `char *`, but it was not. I compared the results for both cases.

This is my code.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define GPIO_BASE   0x3F200000
#define GPFSEL1     0x04
#define GPSET0      0x1C
#define GPCLR0      0x28

int main()
{
    int fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC);
    
    // Error Handling
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("Can't open /dev/mem \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Map pages of memory
    char *gpio_memory_map = (char*)mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                                            MAP_SHARED, fd, GPIO_BASE);
    // Error Handling
    if (gpio_memory_map == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("Error : mmap \n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // GPIO18

    //volatile unsigned int *gpio = (volatile unsigned int*)gpio_memory_map;
    //gpio[GPFSEL1/4] = (1<<24);    

    volatile char *gpio = (volatile char *)gpio_memory_map;
    
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        printf("gpio[%d](%#x) = %#0x\n", i, &gpio[i], gpio[i]);

/*
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        gpio[GPCLR0 / 4] = (1 << 18);
        sleep(1);
        gpio[GPSET0 / 4] = (1 << 18);
        sleep(1);
    }
*/
    // Unmap pages of memory
    munmap(gpio_memory_map, 4096);

    return 0;
}
```

And those below are the results.

1. `volatile unsigned int *gpio = (volatile unsigned int *)gpio_memory_map;`

```ini
gpio[0](0x76f12000) = 0x1
gpio[1](0x76f12004) = 0x1000000
gpio[2](0x76f12008) = 0
gpio[3](0x76f1200c) = 0x3fffffc0
gpio[4](0x76f12010) = 0x24000924
gpio[5](0x76f12014) = 0x924
gpio[6](0x76f12018) = 0
gpio[7](0x76f1201c) = 0x6770696f
gpio[8](0x76f12020) = 0x6770696f
gpio[9](0x76f12024) = 0x6770696f
gpio[10](0x76f12028) = 0x6770696f
gpio[11](0x76f1202c) = 0x6770696f
gpio[12](0x76f12030) = 0x6770696f
gpio[13](0x76f12034) = 0x2ffbbfff
gpio[14](0x76f12038) = 0x3ef4ff
gpio[15](0x76f1203c) = 0
```

2. `volatile char *gpio = (volatile char *)gpio_memory_map;`
   As the result #1 above, I thought `gpio[1]`, `gpio[2]`, `gpio[3]` should be 0. But it was different. And even if I try to write a new value on `gpio[1]` or `gpio[2]` or `gpio[3]`, it stays the same. Why are the results different when approaching `char *` and `unsigned char *`?

```ini
gpio[0](0x76f47000) = 0x1
gpio[1](0x76f47001) = 0x69
gpio[2](0x76f47002) = 0x70
gpio[3](0x76f47003) = 0x67
gpio[4](0x76f47004) = 0
gpio[5](0x76f47005) = 0x69
gpio[6](0x76f47006) = 0x70
gpio[7](0x76f47007) = 0x67
gpio[8](0x76f47008) = 0
gpio[9](0x76f47009) = 0x69
gpio[10](0x76f4700a) = 0x70
gpio[11](0x76f4700b) = 0x67
gpio[12](0x76f4700c) = 0xc0
gpio[13](0x76f4700d) = 0x69
gpio[14](0x76f4700e) = 0x70
gpio[15](0x76f4700f) = 0x67
```

Comment: Consider that an unsigned int is 4 bytes wide while an char is only 1 byte wide.
You may notice that C pointer arithmetic also handles i++ differently for your two types (incrementing by 1 for char, incrementing by 4 for int).
Please update your answer with your research so far and the values you expected to see, so it is easier for people to answer.

Comment: You have different results for the same addresses. Something (likely hardware) won't accept unaligned accesses. I suggest you to figure that out.